# Quickblox : Getting error during send push notification with c# (The remote server returned an error: (422) Unprocessable Entity.)

Tags: c#, android, ios, push-notification, quickblox

I'm getting an error when sending push notifications with c# (The remote server returned an `error: (422) Unprocessable Entity.)`. I am sending `notification` to all possible devices.

Then I am getting an error on this line

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();
```

And here is the code :

```
try
{   
    String token = GetToken();
    HttpWebRequest httpWReq;
    httpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QuickUrl"].ToString().Trim() + "events.xml");

    byte[] plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Pending Request Notification");
    string base64Msg = System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);

    String postData = "event[notification_type]=push";
    postData += "&event[environment]=development";               
    postData += "&event[message]=" + base64Msg;                
    postData += "&event[ios_badge]=" + userPendingFriendRequestCount;
    postData += "&event[ios_sound]=default";
    postData += "&event[user][ids]={" + QuickBloxID + "}";

    ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
    byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
    httpWReq.UserAgent = ".NET Framework Test Client";
    httpWReq.Method = "POST";
    httpWReq.ContentLength = data.Length;
    httpWReq.Headers["QuickBlox-REST-API-Version"] = "0.1.0";
    httpWReq.Headers["QB-Token"] = token;
    using (Stream stream = httpWReq.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();//The remote server returned an error: (422) Unprocessable Entity.
    string responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(responseString);
    IsNotificationSent = true;

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // new ErrorLogger().LogException(ex, "QBBAL-->addupdateDriverUserInQuickBlox");
}
```

Comment: It should be a response body with the explanation, please post

Comment: We are using code for send pus notification request not api.

Comment: @Igor : I am getting error during processing web request.See below attached picture for more details about error.
http://i.imgur.com/BZ3Ev4l.png?1